# cannot get results from prepared statement's fetch()

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement, fetch

This is my code

I tried replacing `SELECT *` with `SELECT booktitle`. If I do `fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)` , that is the default, I get `Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpprepared.php on line 89`. I guess I dont have to `bind_param`, since there are no params here.

```
$query3 = 'SELECT * FROM books';      
$stmt = $db->prepare($query3);
$stmt->execute();    


while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo 'booktitle: '.$row['booktitle'].'<br>';     
}
```

**The problem**

I get the booktitle string echoed 9 times, but no actual data. I am confused on how to use the `fetch`, the results and/or the associative (?) array so I can get the data. Thanks

**Edit**

Wondering if there is a way to simply get everything from a table without having to use `bind_result` or  the combination `get_result - fetch_assoc`.

Thanks

Comment: `while ($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`?

Comment: @BenM Again, it says `Warning: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\phpprepared.php on line 74`

Comment: Yes I know, but that's simply not true. See [`PDO::fetch`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: What is on line 74? Also, are you using PDO or `mysqli`?

Comment: @BenM Oops, I forgot, line 74 is `while ($row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){` . Also check my update

Comment: @BenM I use `$db = new mysqli ('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'books');`

Comment: So this actually doesn't relate to PDO at all, then?

Comment: @BenM I guess not. Are you suggesting I should use PDO instead of `mysqli`?

Comment: See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php). `mysqli::fetch()` **doesn't** accept parameters. Change line 74 to: `while ($row = $stmt->fetch( ))`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the mysqli equivalent is: `$result = $stmt->get_result(); while ($row = $result->get_array(MYSQLI_BOTH )) {...`. MYSQLI_BOTH is the default, so you can skip it.

Comment: @jh1711 Thanks but I get ` Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::get_array() ` for the line `while ($row = $result->get_array()) {  `.

Comment: @BenM Yes, this is what I had in the first place and caused the problem

Comment: @slevin, it should be `fetch_array`not `get_array`. Sorry

Comment: @jh1711 I get `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::get_array() ` for the line `while ($row = $result->get_array()) {  `

Comment: @jh1711 Works if you replace `get_array` with `fetch_array` BUT I search for a way to simply do this, without `bind_result` or the combination `get_result - fetch_assoc` (check the edit in my original question). Unless there is no other way to do this. Thanks

Comment: I don't know a simpler way. You could use `foreach ($result as $row) echo $row['booktitle']`. But you won't be able to access the columns by numeric indexes, and it really just hides the `fetcht_...` behind iterator implementation.